# Navigation Stack Management in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8.1

While we push pages on the nav stack, I was wondering If I could restrict the maximum number of pages to 10 or so to r. For Example,

If the limit is 4 :
    A -> B -> C -> D
now D is on top and A is the root. 
When I try to push E, it should remove B from the stack. Since I need rootVC to remain in place. 
result should be : 
    A -> C -> D -> E.

Also, I know how to remove and add View controllers to the stack, my problem is how to keep track of the navStack while the app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
- (void)limitNavigationStack{
    NSMutableArray* controllers= [self.navCtrl.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    if(controllers.count> MAX_CONTROLLERS){
        [controllers removeObjectAtIndex:1]; // Remove first object after root
        [self.navCtrl setViewControllers:controllers];
    }
}
```

You can put this code in your appDelegate and call it from `viewDidLoad` of your viewController.

To make it more generic as you have pointed out, you can inherit from a base view controller and call this method from its `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` has a property named `viewControllers`. Now just before you are going to push a new view controller you can always check how many objects are present in `self.navigationController.viewControllers`.
If it exceeds your limit then you can go for the navigation stack management manually.

```
if(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > limitCount) {
   // Do the stack management manually for nav controller.
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something more generic. Since I have navigation on multiple pages, I don't want to put the code everywhere... I m thinking of writing a category, though I m not fully satisfied with that idea as well.

Comment: @KP_G It is a different issue that how you want to implement it. But there isn't any other way that can automatically keep a limit on navigation stack. Besides a category or a utility method in a common class is pretty good idea for this implementation.